# Chinese store front

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, language

Which problems could i face with a Chinese storefront? In terms of html encoding and chinese characters. Could i face template/CSS problems Or is it working just like any other EU-languages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please explain your problem in detail and let us know what exact problem are you facing??

Comment: I don't have a problem yet. I have a client who wants to have a Chinese storefront. I never did a Chinese storefront... So i want to have some inside information before i start... Thanks

Comment: it is same as any other store front. You need to install the chinese language pack and get started. It multilanguage right ?

Answer (score 0):

Meez, Check the below link for configure multistore language http://www.joomlart.com/documentation/magento-faqs/setup-magento-multiple-languages-and-currencies
Hope this helps you ?